# Block regular and whatsapp outgoing calls

Tags: call-screening

I want to disable a certain number, not to make regular and WhatsApp outgoing calls  on my sons phone. Is there a way, I can do this , without him knowing about it?

Comment: You want to make it so your son can't dial a certain phone number in both the OS and WhatsApp without him knowing or incoming calls from a number... Actually, nevermind, it doesn't really matter, the answer is no you cannot.

Answer (score 1):

EDIT: It is impossible to do this without your son knowing, as acejavelin said. This answer is the second best thing.

If I think what I think you are saying you, want to block out going calls on your phone? Here's a way to do it:

To block a contact that is saved in your phone

Open WhatsApp.Tap the Menu Button > Settings > Account > Privacy > Blocked contacts.Tap the add contact icon.Select the contact you wish to block from the list.

To block a number that is not saved in your phone

Open the chat with the unknown contact. Tap Block.

When you receive an initial message from an unknown number, you will also have the option to Report spam, which will report and block the user.

**To block calls on your phone:
It varies phone by phone, but here is instruction for some commons OS versions:**

For Marshmallow or Nougat, open Dialer, go to your recent calls list, find the number you want to block and select Block/Report Spam. (If you don't want to report the number as spam, you can uncheck the box.) Then tap Block.

For Lollipop, go to the Phone app and select Call Settings > Call Rejection (ouch) > Auto Reject List. Type in the number or search for it, select it, and you're done.

Sources:

http://www.pcmag.com/article2/0,2817,2476416,00.asp

https://faq.whatsapp.com/en/android/21080506

Comment: It is important to note that the user (the OP's son) would be able to easily undo any of these changes, and they would know easily as well... I took it as a key portion of the questions was "can I do this, without him knowing about it" to which the answer is a definitive no.

Comment: Of course that is impossible, without him knowing, as Android's nature (as you know), but I was thinking that I could answer the second best thing.

Comment: I'll add a note about this in my post. Thanks

Answer (score 1):

My answer is similar to the one already, that is :
Open WhatsApp.Tap the Menu Button > Settings > Account > Privacy > Blocked contacts.Tap the add contact icon.Select the contact you wish to block from the list.